# Otorgar permisos en android 13 kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Que tal tengo el siguiente codigo el cual me permite generar y abrir un pdf desde mi aplicacion, la aplicacion funciona perfectamente en equipos con android 12 o menores pero cuando la instalo en equipos con la actualizacion android 13 una ves me logueo y debe mostrarme el mensaje de si quiero otorgar los permisos de lectura y escritura se cierra la aplicacion y me dice permiso denegado y me voy a configuracion para otorgar los permisos manualmente y no me los muestra solo el de la camara.

MainActivity.kt

```
    private fun checkPermission(): Boolean {
        val permission1 =
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(applicationContext, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        val permission2 =
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(applicationContext, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        return permission1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && permission2 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    private fun requestPermissions() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
            200
        )
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String?>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        if (requestCode == 200) {
            if (grantResults.size > 0) {
                val writeStorage = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                val readStorage = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                if (writeStorage && readStorage) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permiso concedido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permiso denegado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    finish()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!-- If your app doesn't need to access media files that other apps created,
     set the "maxSdkVersion" attribute to "28" instead. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.RetrofitDemo"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="m">
        <activity
            android:name=".PdfVista"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".UserSession"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Agradeceria mucho si me dijeran que estoy haciendo mal

Comment: Únicamente pide el permiso de la cámara, revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a lo que comentas:

> con la actualizacion android 13, me voy a configuracion para otorgar los permisos manualmente y no me
> los muestra solo el de la camara.

Inicialmente, es importante que conozcas lo que indica la documentación

> Si tu app está orientada a Android 11, ni el permiso
> `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` ni el permiso con privilegios
> `WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE` otorgan acceso adicional.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage?hl=es-419

Pero ahora, relacionado con los cambios para Android 13, **si tu app está orientada a Android 13 (`compileSdk 33`), el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`|`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` no se podrá obtener, ya que no es necesario lo requieras**, ya que todos los archivos de tu aplicación se escriben y se leen dentro de la estructura de directorios generada por la aplicación.

Comment: Muchas gracias tienes razon el problema era que como solicitaba la validacion de los permisos la aplicacion me generaba el toast de error pero al comentar la validacion ya abrio correctamente y aun asi me genero y mostro el pdf correctamente muchas gracias